# nsdata ERROR if no data at the URL

Tags: iphone, nsdata

hi i have the below code tryinh to get the image data but sometimes there is no image at the URL and the app is crashing because NSData is not throwing exception. how can we have a timer so we can abort the get data operation is it takes longer.

```
tempData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)nextCatchItem.imageLink]];
```

thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `-dataWithContentsOfURL:` unless the URL is a file:// URL. This executes a synchronous fetch, which is a horrible idea on the main thread, and on background threads it's simply a poor idea (as there's no error reporting). Instead you should use `NSURLConnection`, ideally with the asynchronous API, or with the synchronous API if you're running on a background thread.

Comment: hi and thanks for help. could you refer me to a tutorial? what i am trying to achive is import images from urls and display them. \

Comment: How about the [NSURLConnection programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)?

Comment: yes i was looking into it, have one question about the asynchronous method. if i have to download images of future displays while displaying the present image, how do i set up the nsurlconnection so it downloads in the background without blocking the user interaction? is this possible?

Comment: That's what "asynchronous" means. It doesn't block the run loop while it's downloading. It fires off events as data comes in, and once it tells you that it's complete you can load up the data as an image and display it.

Comment: wow. that was all i needed and was gloomed about it.. thanks heaps:)